# How to set permissions for database in sql azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

Could anyone please tell me how to grant permissions for database in SQL Azure?

When I execute create table query, I am ending up with following message:

> CREATE TABLE permission denied in database testDB

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What user are you connecting to SQL Azure as?  Is it a user that has permissions to create a table (e.g. the admin user created when creating the SQL Azure server)?

Answer (score 10):

Ideally, you'd assign only the the permissions needed for the user. If you've just created a new user that you want to be able do anything in the new database, you can run the following command inside of that database using a server admin user:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'YourNewUser';
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these scripts .This may not be the exact script that you are looking for.But this will help you create the script that you want

STEP1 : Ran these scripts on azure masterdb

```
CREATE LOGIN mydb_admin 
WITH PASSWORD = 'nnn' 
GO
CREATE LOGIN mydb_user 
WITH PASSWORD = 'nnnnnnnnn
GO
```

'

Step2: Ran the below scripts on the actual azure db  eg., mydb

```
CREATE USER mydb_admin  FROM LOGIN mydb_admin ;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'mydb_admin';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'mydb_admin';
GRANT CONNECT TO mydb_admin;
GRANT SELECT TO mydb_admin;
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[procDumpRowsInto_De_Common] TO [mydb_admin] AS [dbo]

CREATE USER mydb_user FROM LOGIN mydb_user;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'mydb_user';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'mydb_user';
GRANT CONNECT TO mydb_user;
GRANT SELECT TO mydb_user;
```

Comment: Please double check your code's formatting. it looks like ' GO is mis-typed .

Answer (score 1):

have a look at: 
[Managing Databases and Logins in SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336235.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you're not trying to run the create table script in the master database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure uses the same security mode as SQL Server. Looks like you use a non-dbo user to create table. I think you can use the GRANT command it get the proper permission.

Comment: SQL Azure works slightly differently to SQL Server in terms of security - uses different roles for the logins and users IIRC.